# Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' when running XamarinStore.Droid

Tags: android, xamarin, json.net, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run the Xamarin Studio Sample app XamarinStore for Android.

Though, when I try to run the app, I get the following build error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(675,2): monodroid error XA0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. 
Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

I already have Json.NET framework on my Components folder. 
And I also have Newtonsoft.Json reference in my References folder.

What could possibly be wrong with my installation/configuration?

Comment: Try removing and adding the Json component from the component store. Clean the solution -> build it -> close the studio and reopen it.

Comment: @Alex.F I already did it and the same still happens. If I remove the component, it complains about Json namespace not found, as it is expected.

Comment: What version is the component?

Comment: @Alex.F It's Json.NET 4.5.11.1 and NewtonSoft.Json 4.5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my Newtonsoft.JSon reference folder was not being found, nor was my SDK folder, due to having a Windows username with special characters (João).

I copied my Android SDK to a folder with no Special characters and changed the SDK location in Tools -> Options and I managed to get it working.

This issue was reported in https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27074 and it is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 2):

The components automatically get downloaded for you. They should be in a components/android/lib folder. You could add it manually. Additionally, if the component isn't working try to add the Json.NET nuget package instead.

Comment: When I try to add the JSON.Net package I get the following message "Adding Newtonsoft.Json...
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6' to XamarinStore.Droid.
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: Do you know from which rep branch should we load the project in Xamarin Studio?